# EF Core stop recursion on theninclude

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using .NET Core 3 with the latest Entity Framework Core. I currently have 3 tables, two normal tables and one linking table. They are structured below. I am trying to get the accessory by itself for the vehicle it is linked to, what currently is happening is that it recurses back into itself and loads the vehicle object again (since it has a reference to the linking table). Does anyone know how I can stop this recursion from taking place? I don't want the `VehicleAccessory` to have the `vehicleAccessories` array within it, that is causing the recursion.

**Call**

```
var result = _context.Vehicles
            .Include(x => x.VehicleAccessories)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Accessory)
            .Include(x => x.VehicleImages)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Image)
            .ToList();
        return result;
```

**Call result**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "registrationNumber": "123456",
    "make": "BMW",
    "model": "M3",
    "year": 2009,
    "kilometers": 10030,
    "vehicleIdentificationNumber": "1234567890",
    "retailPrice": 100000.00,
    "costPrice": 50000.00,
    "vehicleAccessories": [
        {
            "vehicleId": 1,
            "accessoryId": 1,
            "accessory": {
                "id": 1,
                "description": "NEW ONE",
                "vehicleAccessories": []
            }
        },
        {
            "vehicleId": 1,
            "accessoryId": 2,
            "accessory": {
                "id": 2,
                "description": "NEW ONE",
                "vehicleAccessories": [
                    {
                        "vehicleId": 2,
                        "vehicle": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "registrationNumber": "123456",
                            "make": "BMW",
                            "model": "M3",
                            "year": 2009,
                            "kilometers": 10030,
                            "vehicleIdentificationNumber": "1234567890",
                            "retailPrice": 100000.00,
                            "costPrice": 50000.00,
                            "vehicleAccessories": [],
                            "vehicleImages": [],
                            "dtCreated": "2020-02-03T11:21:48.2245986",
                            "dtUpdated": "2020-02-03T11:21:48.2245554"
                        },
                        "accessoryId": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "vehicleImages": [],
    "dtCreated": "2020-02-03T11:20:13.8890848",
    "dtUpdated": "2020-02-03T11:20:13.8890488"
}
```

**Vehicle table:**

```
public class Vehicle
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Kilometers { get; set; }
    public string VehicleIdentificationNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal RetailPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal CostPrice { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VehicleAccessory> VehicleAccessories { get; } = new List<VehicleAccessory>();
    public ICollection<VehicleImage> VehicleImages { get; set; }
    public DateTime DTCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DTUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

**Accessory Table**

```
public class Accessory
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VehicleAccessory> VehicleAccessories { get; } = new List<VehicleAccessory>();
}
```

**Linking Table**

```
public class VehicleAccessory
{
    public long VehicleId { get; set; }
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

    public long AccessoryId { get; set; }
    public Accessory Accessory { get; set; }
}
```

**Relationship in context**

```
builder.Entity<VehicleAccessory>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.AccessoryId, t.VehicleId });
```

Comment: Can you show the query code?

Comment: @Darem - Added the call

Comment: may be you need to enable lazy loading mode, check this blog https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/lazy-loading